# Getting Date form three combo boxes as dd/mm/yyyy using ASP and VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, combobox

I am trying to take the date from the user in the form of drop down list as below my ASP code:

**ASP Code**

```
 <div class="content-topwidth">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDOB" runat="server" Text="Label">Enter DOB</asp:Label>
                    <div id="three-cases-cal">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDay" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Something like this:**

[image: DOB]

I have to code it in VB and to save the values from these combo boxes in the database.

E.g: I have a table of ***USERINFO*** and there is a column as ***DOB*** so the date getting from these combo boxes to store in this column as dd/mm/yyyy.

Can anyone help me with VB code.

Thank you

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a calendar control?

Comment: @AbdulAziz: then what's the problem?

Comment: Make sure that you use a DateTime column in the database, and NOT varchar or other character type column.  It will make things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have write this code in the Page_Load event of the Page, Hope it helps you

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

Dim mdate As String = ddlDay.ToString() & "/" & ddlMonth.ToString() & "/" & ddlYear.ToString()

Dim connection As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" 'Change datasource, username and password Datasource may be . or if you have sqlexpress then it be .\SqlExpress

    Dim query As String = "Insret into USERINFO(DOB) VALUES('"&mdate&"');"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(connection)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = query
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't store dates as strings!!  And your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.  Use parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate day, month, and year values and convert string date to `DateTime` using `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` method.

```
Dim str=ddlDay.SelectedValue & "-" & ddlMonth.SelectedValue & "-" & ddlYear.SelectedValue
Dim myDate as DateTime
IF DateTime.TryParseExact(str,"dd-MM-yyyy",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
          System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,myDate) Then
   //valid date
End IF
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to collect the values and save to DateTime

```
Dim year as integer = CInt(ddlYear.SelectedValue)
Dim month as integer = CInt(ddlMonth.SelectedValue)
Dim day as integer = CInt(ddlDay.SelectedValue)

Dim DOB as DateTime  = New DateTime(year, month, day)
```

So you can save DOB in the database

To set the values while editing the page

Use this

```
ddlYear.SelectedValue = DOB.Year.ToString()
ddlMonth.SelectedValue = DOB.Month.ToString()
ddlDay.SelectedValue = DOB.Day.ToString()
```